# Error when compiling openjdk8 in centos 6.10

Tags: java, centos

I completely cloned the openjdk8 project.

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u
cd jdk8u/
```

exec script:

```
./get_source.sh
```

These are all executed smoothly.

but,

```
./configure
```

error message: /root/jdk8u/common/autoconf/configure: line 197: /root/jdk8u/generated-configure.sh: No such file or directory

```
[root@localhost jdk8u]# ./configure 
Configure source code has been updated, checking time stamps
Running generated-configure.sh
/root/jdk8u/common/autoconf/configure: line 197: /root/jdk8u/generated-configure.sh: No such file or directory
configure exiting with result code 1
[root@localhost jdk8u]#
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved because the source code is not completely downloaded. Just execute get_source.sh a few times.